# How are user privileges implemented in multi-user websites securely?

Tags: ajax

An “Add Link” button is added to the page by JavaScript after the user is authenticated (sign in). The user clicks on the “Add Link” button which opens up a form (implementable by JavaScript) for the user to fill out and submit. When the form is submitted an Ajax request is sent to the server, the server stores the newly added link into a database. How are user privileges implemented in multi-user websites securely? Are they implemented on the client side or on the server side, or a combination of both?

Answer (score 0):

A little of both, but generally speaking more on the server side. A user that authenticates might get a session ID key which they can store locally or else they are tracked by the server (presumably by IP address). That user has some permissions associated with their account in a database on the server. Those permissions are then read when the user attempts to perform a restricted action.

Comment: How are control or form buttons displayed on the client after authentication? Are they unhidden, added to the page (appendChild), should they come from the server or hidden in the client?

Comment: If they contain sensitive or restricted information they should be retrieved from the server either with JavaScript or maybe embedded in a template. It really depends on the situation.